# Google Drive SDK and Unicode filenames

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I’m using [OpenFileActivityBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/OpenFileActivityBuilder.html) from Google Drive SDK for Android to prompt the user about saving a file to Google Drive. Saving itself goes totally fine, but when I set the title to non-English text, such as Russian, the saved file has question marks instead of symbols. For example, I set title to “Файл” and created file has filename “????”. The thing is if user enters the title himself Cyrillic symbols are translated to question marks as well. This issue is applied to any example—even [official quickstart app](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart)—just enter non-English characters (“Файл”, “ø”) into a file title and you’ll get question marks at created filename as well.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I thought this is my fault, but I’m obtaining string from resources, plus when user enters title himself it is definitely Unicode already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug :-/ Sorry, we are looking into it.

Comment: Would be great if you could post later confirmation if it is a bug or not so I can mark your answer as accepted. If it is a bug I see no workarounds before the fix unfortunately.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in the Google Play Services 4.3. Anyway, it would be nice to have some kind of an official issues tracker like we have for the Google Maps SDK.